# Unable to store data in sqlite db with Python / SQLAlchemy (Flask)

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Hello I'm struggling with this error since weeks.
In my python/flask app I need to store a pw in a db table user in SQLite with SQLalchemy.
The table seemds to be correctly created when I check sqlite> .schema the column pwd is there.
When I run the app it returns an error saying the column pwd does not exist (see error below).
I tried several times dropping the table, trying in a new db but nothing, I think the table is created correctly but there must be something wrong in the code? Could also be the db that was messed up but I don't think so.

Here I create the table and define the User class, as per official SQLAlchemy documentation

```
from flask import Flask 
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from sqlalchemy import *

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///data-users.sqlite'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key = True, autoincrement=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique = True)
    pwd = db.Column(db.String())

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username
```

Here I store the user data in the table

```
        from store_user_db import User, db
        db.create_all()

        DICP_FTP_DESTINATION_PSW=self.submit_pwd()

        user = User(id=001,username="ita_itf",pwd=DICP_FTP_DESTINATION_PSW)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
```

This is the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError

OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table user has no column named pwd
[SQL: INSERT INTO user (id, username, pwd) VALUES (?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: (1, 'ita_itf', <read-only buffer for 0x7efe495709f0, size -1, offset 0 at 0x7.....
```

Comment: How about calling `db.create_all()` you definition of User Model class?
And I don't think you need to add `meta` and `usertable`

Comment: db.create_all() won't do anything the table is already created in the Metadata() part, If I remove that the table wont be created, from my understanding the code in the User class is just to define the class user, not to create the table, to create a table you must use the function Table()

Comment: So if I remove the #CREATE TABLE code with metadata etc, I reinizialize the db, drop the table, then run the app, the error message is the same. So basically is how I thought, is not trying to store the data in the table I created, but is storing it in an unexisting table.

Comment: It's unusual to use `meta` and `usertable` in the way that you are using them in pure [flask-sqlalchemy](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) apps.  It might be helpful to set `SQLALCHEMY_ECHO` to `True` in your config so we can see the commands that are being sent to the database.

Comment: Ok then supposing I won't use meta, how do I create a new table in the db? what's the code?

Comment: `db.create_all()`

Comment: I understand this but how do I tell the dm the column names? I mean the wwhole code to create a table with column names and type

Comment: have you considered reading the metadata back from the engine, and create tables in a different program or console? it might help you to debug the situation. Once you read the metadata, you can check if the tables and all columns actually exist in the db

Comment: The `User` class provides the table/column metadata for `db.create_all()`

Comment: ok but if I only run the app without the code I wrote in the #CREATE TABLE part, it won't create any user table, at least if I run it with that code, it actually creates the table and I can see it in sqlite. I think I should just find the way to reference to that table I just created in the def init function, maybe tablename='user' is not enough ?

Comment: Can you go to the sqlite console (`sqlite3 data-users.sqlite` on mac/linux, I guess `sqlite3.exe data-users.sqlite` on Windows) and run the command `.dump user`, and [edit] the question to include the output please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience flask and SQlAlchemy, but here is a sample app which is working for me.
The Model definitions are taken from the documentation and added a test model during runtime to see if it is still able to create new tables and it did.

If you have a large app, I'd prefer to use `flask-migrate` library which can create versioned migrations from your models for creating/modifying your tables.

```py
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, request, flash, url_for, redirect, json
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username

class Category(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Category %r>' % self.name

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    body = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    pub_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False,
        default=datetime.utcnow)

    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'),
        nullable=False)
    category = db.relationship('Category',
        backref=db.backref('posts', lazy=True))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Post %r>' % self.title

class Test(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Test %r>' % self.name

def insertAdminUser():
    admin = User(username='admin', email='admin@example.com')
    db.session.add(admin)
    db.session.commit()

@app.route('/insert-admin', methods = ['GET'])
def insertAdmin():
    insertAdminUser()

    return app.response_class(
        response=json.dumps({
            "message": "inserted"
        }),
        mimetype='application/json'
    )
if __name__ == '__main__':
   db.create_all()
   app.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: ok I see, so I notice the main difference is that in the code you posted the def in the User class it returns something, while my def __init__ doesn't return anything, based on the code I wrote, do you think my User class def function should return something? In my case I should pass id, user and password, so should return all of them? how do I write that in practice? I'm quite a newbie on python

Comment: In python `__repr__` return the object representation of the class and isn't required. And `__init__` (constructor) is a method called when a new instance is created and doesn't have to return anything. You can define/override you own `__init__` method.
I think you should first learn about Python OOP.

Comment: Here's explained pretty well, seems so simple but in this way it won't create any table in my db! https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/

Comment: I know that about init indeed I was speaking about __repr__

Comment: If I do it like in the article it won't even create the db file

Comment: I have read some more documentation so one important thing to consider is that I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy and not just sqlalchemy, so I have updated the code in my post here, simplified as per Flask-SQLAlchemy documentation. In this way it should work perfectly, the only issue now is that is not creating the db file, I tried renaming it to a new sqlite db path, but it won't create the db, I think maybe I should add the engine function but not sure where I have to pass it in the code